# Install and data-install script with different versions?

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script, data-script

I have a custom module with several install and upgrade scripts under the sql directory, that create and alter my sql table.

When Magento runs the scripts it updates both `version` and `data_version` fields in `core_resource` table.

Now I need to add a data script to add data to the table. If I create a `data-install-0.1.0.php` under my data directory, it wouldn't run since version in DB is already 0.1.3.

The only way I could make it work is naming my data script `data-upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php` and changing version in `config.xml` to 0.1.4. Of course this sets also `version` (resource version) to 0.1.4.

If in the future I want to create an sql upgrade script will it have to be `upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.5.php` or `upgrade-0.1.4-0.1.5.php`?

Is this the correct way to do it? Is there any way to change only `version` or only `data_version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You next upgrade or data upgrade script will need to be `upgrade-0.1.4-0.1.5.php`

Both columns will be updated in the database so you are required to create `old.version-new.version`

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Seems weird to manage two version variables if they always get updated together...

Comment: I'm afraid so. The data version and module version both get set to what is in the modules config.xml